# Python Maria DB MYSQL Type Cast Error Incorrect double value: ''237'' for column `wtx520`.`weather`.`value` at row 1

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a Raspi Python project where I want to store values of a Weather sensor in a DB. The values come in a String. I was able to separate it, but I make a stupid mistake and can not store the values.
Code

```
mport mysql.connector
import re
db =mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, db='wtx520', password='xxx', user='xxx')
#port 3307 für synology
#example string
line ="0r1,Dn=237D,Dm=237D,Dx=237D,Sn=0.1N,Sm=0.2N,Sx=0.3NLq@"
pair = line.split(",")

for i in pair:
    value = i.split("=")

    print(value[0])
    if len(value)>1: 

     decvalue =re.findall("\d*\.?\d+", value[1])

     key= value[0]
     #remove brackets around dec value
     inserttuple=(key,str(decvalue).replace('[','').replace(']',''))
     #inserttuple=(str(key), "237") it works with this static example
     sql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO weather (valuekey, value) VALUES (%s,%s)"""

     mycursor = db.cursor()
     result  = mycursor.execute(sql_insert_query,inserttuple)
     db.commit()
```

DB Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE wtx520.weather (
  ts TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  value DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
  valuekey VARCHAR(4) DEFAULT NULL
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 1365,
CHARACTER SET utf8,
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Error:
  Nachricht = 1366 (22007): Incorrect double value: ''237'' for column `wtx520`.`weather`.`value` at row 1
  Quelle = 
  Stapelüberwachung:
  File "C:\Users\Marcel\source\repos\wtx520-azure\wtx520-azure\wtx520_azure.py", line 22, in 
    result  = mycursor.execute(sql_insert_query,inserttuple)

any help apprechiated

Comment: check for the real content .. of  inserttuple ...

Comment: thanks!Looks like that inserttuple = ('Dn', "'237'") how do I get rid of the single quotation marks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is:

inserttuple=(key,str(decvalue).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'",''))

thanks for the hint!